# how to update an element from specific index in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, getter-setter

How to update an element from an Arrayist that consists of another ArrayList?

I have a class named `Product` that consist of `name`, `type`, `currentQuantity`, `purchaseQuantity`. I have created an ArrayList called `productList` to store each product's data that has been added into into `Product` class.

My problem is when I go to another class and I want to update the `toPurchase` element of a specific product of index `i`, I am now confused on how to do so.

I have declared this in the class:

```
private ArrayList<Product> productList;
```

And I tried doing this:

```
productList.set(productIndex, product.setPurchaseQuantity(pPurchaseQuantity));
```

But there's a red line underneath `product.setPurchaseQuantity(pPurchaseQuantity)` that mentioned this:

> Required type: Product
> Provided: void

So far that those are the only code in my new class.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: My crystal ball says that the problem is not the expression you present itself, but that method `Product.setPurchaseQuantity(int)` returns `void`, and you are attempting to assign its return value to a variable or to return it from a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type mismatch happens because `product.setPurchaseQuantity(pPurchaseQuantity)` returns `void` but `productList.set(...)` requires an object of type `Product` as its second argument.

To update the quantity, you need to *get* a `Product` from the `productList` and then **operate on the retrieved object**. There is no need to *set* this object again since you are changing an attribute of this object and the reference to it remains in the `productList`.

```
Product product = productList.get(productIndex);
product.setPurchaseQuantity(pPurchaseQuantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically are not changing any thing in arrayList, what you want to do is to update an object which is already referenced in this arrayList, to do so you can just get this object and update (see below)

```
productList.get(productIndex).setPurchaseQuantity(pPurchaseQuantity)
```